# Why did the order of my script give a Divide by Zero error?

Tags: divide-by-zero

I'm working on some beginner Python exercises. I have the following, working code:

```
# Use the file name mbox-short.txt as the file name
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
inp=fh.readlines()
count=0
total=0.0
for line in inp:
    line=line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"): 
        continue
    value=line[19:]
    value=float(value)
    count=count+1   
    total=total + value
print "Average spam confidence:",total/count
```

When I first wrote this, I put the "count" line before the "value" line like this:

```
# Use the file name mbox-short.txt as the file name
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
inp=fh.readlines()
count=0
total=0.0
for line in inp:
    line=line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"): 
        continue
    count=count+1           
    value=line[19:]
    value=float(value)
    total=total + value
print "Average spam confidence:",total/count
```

This resulted in a divide by zero error. Why?

Comment: Both pieces of code look correct to me.  You would get a divide by zero error if inp is empty.  Are you sure your input is the same in both cases?

Comment: I thought the same thing and double checked the input, but it was the same in both cases.

Comment: Can you post the input file?

Comment: I cannot- it's too long. But the hyperlink is here: http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/mbox-short.txt